# Why Are Mercurial Tags Unique?

Tags: mercurial

To me, the notion of a "tag" is a quick label you apply to something as an easy reminder. But you can't have a tag like that in HG because you could only have it once. You'd have to add a timestamp or such to it.

What is the reasoning behind having unique tags in HG? Is there a mechanism in HG that would allow me to find "all changesets I marked as X"?

Comment: Because they're not really tags in the folksonomic sense, but rather named revisions.

Comment: I did not know that. So I'm just getting caught up on the name?

Comment: @Josh: Probably. If you had 2 changesets with the same tag `myTag`, how is hg supposed to know which you mean when you say something like `hg update -r myTag`?

Comment: Is there a particular thing that you're wanting to do? A specific thing you're wanting to use a generic changeset labelling system for? (Linking automated test results, code review, etc.?)

Comment: @Chris: No, I'm more after the general concept (though your examples are good and would be useful to me). I didn't know one could do what Joel just suggested. But again, the word "tag" brings to mind "holiday 2010" and "tutorial" (obviously, you prob won't be tagging your repos with those, but you get my drift) and I never realized that their purpose was a "unique, named identifier for a change set".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags are for tagging the particular state of the repository at such-and-such a time. Version 1.0 as `v1.0`, and things like that. Tagging releases is the most common usage. It's not intended for "the current release"; branches are more suitable for that.

You can work with all sorts of different branching techniques; one is to have a "deployment" branch (perhaps the default branch, or called "release", or "deploy"—whatever you want) from which you make your releases. Do work in another branch or branches, and then merge into the release branch for making releases (and then, of course, you get to tag them).

I would advise you to read about branches and tags from something like [*Chapter 8. Managing releases and branchy development* in *Mercurial: The Definitive Guide*](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html).

---

There's no built-in way of adding "labels" to changesets. Things like [hg-review](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/hg-review/) (for code review—a project well worth looking at), when they want to add information to changesets, store it in their own location in their own way and link it in their own way through their own commands.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do use branches for all versions and releases. `deploy` was a bad example. More interested in "all changesets I marked with X"

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. You want to have some way of labelling changesets, e.g. you might have an automatic test runner which would then label changesets as "tests-failed" or "tests-succeeded"?

Comment: Yes! That is a better example than the one I thought of. But based on the name "tag" that's how I thought it would work.

Comment: the commit message would seem to be the natural place for that sort of thing

Comment: @jk. the problem with that is applying labels afterwards. Can you change the commit message after committing?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the tag docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Tag#How_do_tags_work_in_Mercurial.3F) at mercurial wiki.